# Can I pass arguments to angular-cli at build-time

Tags: typescript, angular, build-tools, angular-cli

I would like to pass custom arguments to `angular-cli` when building an `Angular2` (typescript) app. Is this possible? How can I access this arguments in my code?

The scenario is like this: I have one `Angular2` app with 2 layouts. Each layout has 3 colors (red, blue, green). I want to build all possible combinations. One app per layout and color => layout1red, layout1green, layout2blue, ...

I want to create 6 JSON config files for each build where I define the layout and color, and maybe some additional properties.

Answer (score 23):

It is possible to create multiple configuration files with `@angular/cli`.

As mentioned in [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#build-targets-and-environment-files) custom configuration files can be add in the following way:

- create a `src/environments/environment.NAME.ts`
- add `{ "NAME": 'src/environments/environment.NAME.ts' }` to the `apps[0].environments` object in `.angular-cli.json`
- use them via the `--env=NAME` flag on the build/serve commands.

So, you would probably need 6 config files for dev and 6 config files for prod.

And then to access those variables just  import environment object from `environment.ts` file.

Comment: It i for adding a new environment not passing an argument. My argument can range from -360 to + 360. I cannot create an environment per value.

Comment: @Arashsoft, the fact that you cannot solve your problem with suggested approach doesn't mean the answer is wrong :) If you could post a separate question describing what are you trying to achieve I could have a look.

Comment: The question is clear: "Can I pass arguments to angular-cli at build-time". It is not about creating environments. It is about passing arguments and this post does not answer that.

Comment: The answer IS wrong. OP was asking if arguments can be passed to the CLI at builtime (i.e. ng build) and if it was possible to retrieve these arguments at runtime. I'm looking at the exact same thing right now in order to include a build number in my code automatically in my CD environment (instead of using hacky way to replace environment variables with a script).

Comment: not a solution env files are not parameters. How do you manage secrets?

Comment: The `--env=NAME` param has changed to `--configuration NAME`

Answer (score 4):

I didn't get your question fully, I can think of two ways of making this happen :

A- Passing arguments when generating a new project :

1- In order to be able to pass arguments to the angular cli, you need to understand where would you want it to be used.

If those configurations are used in your layout, you can fork the Angular cli and update it's blueprint and easily add your own configuration.

Here is the components blueprint :

```
     angular-cli/packages/@angular/cli/blueprints/component/files/__path__/__name__.component.ts
```

Which looks like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: '<%= selector %>',<% if(inlineTemplate) { %>
  template: `
```

you see `selector` ? that's the name of the component which you can play with and at the end when you're creating a new project, you can pass your own flags there and use it.

But this is not the best idea because you're always in trouble when Angular cli gets updated.

2- The other possible solution is to use `ng eject`

This will generate the `webpack` configuration in a separate file and puts it in your project root folder, you can then play with that file and provide your configuration and make it customised per your app.

But again, I'm not sure how do you want to use that configuration.

This is a perfect candidate for your `build time` configuration.

3- Use the `environments` configuration:

As it's already been answered, this is also very convenient for providing `build time` configuration :

Follow `@mikedanylov`'s answer and then use it like this in your files :

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if(environment.colorRed==='blue'){

     console.log('the color is blue');

}


 npm build -e=colorRed
```

---

B: `Run time` :

This is a better option, you can create a call in your index.html like this :

```
  <script src="wherever/configurations/blue"></script>
```

and then inside the configuration, you might have :

```
  var configuration = {
      whatEver:"blue"
  }
```

and because this is a script, it'l be available everywhere and you can access it in your components :

```
export class MyComponent{


    ngOnInit(){
        console.log('colour is : '+window['configuration.whatEver']); // obviously you can improve this and create type definitions and what not.
    }
}
```

This will give you more flexibility on updating your configuration in future without having to build your app again.

Obviously, you can make the same call through an Ajax call, but I find above to be more application agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

just an update to the answers.
You have several options:

1. To run multiple configurations, simply create a new configuration object in `angular.json` look in `projects.[your project].architect.build.configurations` there you can craete a new configuration object and make changes to `fileReplacements`. To run this new config just use ng build `--c=my_new_env_name`
2. if you choose to have to replace more than the configurations file, maybe to use a different css file entirely then you can add a new project in `angular.json` just add a new project object in `projects.[my new project name]` and modify the `styles` section. Once you are happy with your new project configuration, simple run `ng build my-new-project-name` or `ng serve my-new-project-name`

the choice is your and you can play around with `angular.json` see the documentation https://angular.io/cli/build