# Access system variable (Environment Variable) while building Angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to build my Angular application using one system variable.

**System Variable**

```
server_url = http://google.com
```

My Environment.ts file look like

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  serveUrl: 'http://someurl.com',
  mleServerUrl: 'http://someurl2.com',
  botServerUrl: 'http://someurl2.com',
  DEBUG_LOG: true,
  azureAD: true,
  mleEnvironment: 'dev',
  multtenant: true,
  e2eTest: false
};
```

I need to replace serveUrl value with http://google.com while executing `ng build` command.

Comment: If it needs to be set at build time, just create a npm script that retrieves the environment variable and repalces the value in the environment file before running ng build?

Answer (score 1):

You need a environment.prod.ts (in the same folder as environment.ts) with

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  serveUrl: 'http://google.com',
};
```

then you have to do a `ng build --prod`

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: the requirement is such there can be `N` number of different URL on different machine. So need to access system variable only.

Comment: There's no N number of URLs, if you do that you'll get 
serveUrl that is equal "http://someurl.com" in development 
serveUrl that is equal "http://google.com" in production

In your code you can access it with `environment.serveUrl`

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but I feel like that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Let’s take another example of three person A,B,C where A is fond of using google.com and B likes to use yahoo.com and C like bing.com. Assume that they all have that url in the system variables called server_url. Now while building angular application on these three machine it will read the server_url from these machines and put that value in environment.ts file and use it.

Comment: It will be like building the angular application based on system variables. Now you can totally assume that system variable will always be there.

Comment: the browser cannot read the system variables, you will have to set it during the build. I'm not sure if this is possible with angular-cli. 

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889613/9136781 maybe, it can help you.

Comment: I just need cli to pass that variable value while in building phase not during run time

Comment: That's what I said, during ng-build

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use system environment variables instead of the standard angular approach here are a few options:

1. Create a env service that is available through your Angular app; leverages a `env.js` file which can be modified at deploy time.  https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/
2. Modify your webpack process with a custom angular build which allows you to read system environment variables at build time https://blog.usejournal.com/system-environment-variables-in-angular-1f4a922c7b4c