# Dynamic angular service calls

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I am new to Angular. I am currently developing a simple angular app that get data from java service (running in same machine) and display it in screen.
We know for sure that angular app and java back end service will be deployed in same machine, but we dont have any control over the machine where it will be deployed.

So i should have a way in angular to get IP address of the machine and call the service correctly. I will be more happy if there is better way to do this.

Note: I am using angular 5.

Comment: How come angular know about the server machine IP address where you deployed? You need to give that in constant file in order to access the service.

Comment: @srigar Understood. But as i have mentioned it cannot be constant as we may deploy this in different machine. Also we are deploying angular ui and service using docker compose. Is there a way to pass param while building using angular-cli ?

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205690/can-i-pass-arguments-to-angular-cli-at-build-time?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You are using ip and not dns?

Comment: @Yftach yes IP not DNS.

Comment: Try to get the Router.url 
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute