# Is there a way to pass arguments by CLI when building an Angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, environment-variables, angular-cli, build-tools

I'm using Angular 16 and I have a specific scenario: My application will run locally in many machines, each one with one different ip, so that means that every server url will be different. Currently, I'm getting this url from the `environment.ts`, like this:

```
export const environment = {
    apiUrl: 'http://11.22.33.44:5678/',
};
```

Currently, every time I need to build the application, I change the *url* manually. I want to do this by a CLI command. i.e `ng build --configuration=production --serverUrl=http://55.66.77.88:5678/`.

This is my `angular.json` *production* section

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.development.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.ts"
      }
    ]
}
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205690/can-i-pass-arguments-to-angular-cli-at-build-time), but it says that I'll need to create one environment for each scenario. It's not fully dynamic.

Comment: you could use apiUrl: '/'  Which would make it relative.  In production you should be same domain.

Comment: I have some scenarios where I'm not the same domain. But thanks, it will help me anyway

Answer (score 1):

First, try to set a placeholder value for `apiUrl`:

```
export const environment = {
    apiUrl: 'PLACEHOLDER_VALUE',
};
```

Then, when building your project you can use the `--env` option to specify the `apiUrl` environment variable value, like:

```
ng build --configuration=production --env.apiUrl='YOUR_ACTUAL_API_HERE'
```